# Need to Change ids of records from SugarCRM Export for Accounts and Contacts

Tags: csv, export, lookup, sugarcrm, lookup-tables

I have a bit of a complex issue to deal with here at the moment and would love some help please.

I have exported data from SugarCRM in CSV format to be imported in to my new app. Now my app works slightly differently in terms of database schema. I use auto-incrementing integers for id's where as SugarCRM uses long alphanumeric strings like dc4c072c-ec0e-26b6-8780-4a9e7ec8375d.

I need to be able to take the data for say accounts and contacts, using the SugarCRM pivot table export from accounts_contacts, and change the id's, while keeping them all linked correctly. I then need to use the changed data to import in to my database, where each record in the contacts table contains an account_id field which links them to accounts, rather than a pivot table.

Now, my first thoughts would be to import all the required data in to clean database and use a lookup table with four fields in it to change the id's. So I would have old_account_id, new_account_id, old_contact_id, new_contact_id. I'd then use that table to find the right id's and amend the data.

The only issue I have with this, is that my SQL isn't amazing, so I'm having difficulty visualising and writing the query to use the lookup table and change the data. So I would love some help with this.

Also, once I have the query and the correct amended data, I need another query to then create the contacts table using an account_id field from the pivot table.

Hope you guys can help out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you planning on keeping the data in sync? I'd suggest adding a "sugar_id" column in your app and a "your_app_id" column in SugarCRM. This way the native id column remains the same and that it will maintain a reference to the record in the other system.